# Gradle Version Resolution Problem: Building Xcore

Tags: gradle, xtext, xcore

#### Background

I'm trying to build a project which has a dependency on a library [xcore 1.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore/1.10.0) that has a dependency on [antlr](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr-runtime) with restriction `[3.2.0, 3.2.1)`. What exists is a version `3.2`.

#### Problem

The build fails reporting `Could not find any version that matches org.antlr:antlr-runtime:[3.2.0, 3.2.1).`. When I explicitly ask for version `3.2`, it resolves. When I check `ava -cp "$MAVEN_HOME/lib/*" org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion 3.2 3.2.0 3.2.1`, I get the following (which I interpret as 3.2 being within the requested racket):

```
1. 3.2 == 3.2
   3.2 == 3.2.0
2. 3.2.0 == 3.2
   3.2.0 < 3.2.1
3. 3.2.1 == 3.2.1
```

#### Reporduction

To try this at home, one should be able to check out [this example project](https://github.com/itemis/itemis-blog/tree/xcore_gradle) and try running `./gradlew clean build`.

#### Questions

- Is the version bracket wrongly specified (given the versions that actually exist and assuming version `3.2` is required)? Or is Gradle doing something weird with the interpretation of the version bracket?
- Is there a way to work around this (other than uploading a "fake" replica with version `3.2.0` to a local repository)?

Comment: i assume this is a general problem with ranges behaving different in maven gradle and osgi. did you consider to simply exclude the antlr dependency from xcore and take the once from xtext instead https://github.com/itemis/itemis-blog/blob/69b4c986af84538746f677b9c9ec4c447deb02fe/org.xtext.example.mydsl.parent/org.xtext.example.mydsl/build.gradle#L19

Comment: btw this new xcore version is not officially supported by xtext. see https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/issues/1282

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDietrich, didn't realize there was an incompatibility. Building with 1.3.1 for now. Would you mind letting me know when the new version is supported so I can upgrade? On a related matter, do you know whether the upgrade will remove the need to have the xcore model in a project separat from the xtext one?

Comment: when somebody finds the time doing it or gets incentivized to do so otherwise